# How to find the missing time value using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

My `dataset` is `minute` based.

When I do `df['Gmt time'].diff().max()` I get `Timedelta('0 days 00:02:00')`. But the `dataset` is a `minute` based.

My `df` looks like this but there are `million` of data point so I am looking to see where is the missing data.

```
Gmt time, Open
2019-09-08 1:00:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:01:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:02:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:03:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:04:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:05:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:06:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:07:00, 1.1025 
2019-09-08 1:08:00, 1.1025 
2019-09-08 1:09:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:10:00, 1.1026 
2019-09-08 1:11:00, 1.1026
....
```

How can I locate where the `data` is missing?

Comment: Add an example of dataframe input. Thanks

Comment: @Massifox added sample `dataset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You data does not have missing timestamp. But you can do:

```
set(pd.date_range(df['Gmt time'].min(), 
                  df['Gmt time'].max(), 
                  freq='min')
   ) - set(df['Gmt time'])
```

to get the set of those. Output for this data:

```
set()
```

Comment: By doing `set()`, my output is itself, `set()`, however the first `code` worked. Thank you!